# Jersey Client API - Read data

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jersey, jax-ws

I'm using the Jersey client API to read data but below code is throwing below Exception:
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:

```
        String url = "XXXX";
    String name = "UserName";
    String password = "Password";
    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().
         encode(authString.getBytes());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String resp;
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);

    ClientResponse clientResp = webResource.accept("application/json").
        header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc).get
        (ClientResponse.class);

    resp = clientResp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("response: " + resp);

   if(clientResp.getStatus() != 200){
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }

    try {
        SNApplicationLst snApplnLst = mapper.readValue(resp, 
                     SNApplicationLst.class);

         for(SNApplication snAppln: snApplnLst.getResult()) {
                System.out.println("name:" + snAppln.getName() 
                    + " :: application_id:" + snAppln.getU_application_id());




            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output: After running code above code, exception is throwing. Can anyone please help me on this

```
   Exception in thread "main" 
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: 
   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle
    (URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get   
    (WebResource.java:507)
at sailpoint.custom.Test.main(Test.java:41)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
    (Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown 
     Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown 
    Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode
    (Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke
   (URLConnectionClientHandler.java:249)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle
    (URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Whats the full stack trace?

Comment: Add this comment in as an edit into your original post.